# How to create a dynamic routing which includes Hyphen in .net core?

Tags: jquery, .net-core

I want my route to be like this
https://www.example.com/career/hiring-react
Here 'react' keyword should be changed as per the click event. Suppose there is a page in which it includes some positions such as react, .net, flutter so on. If someone clicks on flutter url should be change to https://www.example.com/career/hiring-flutter.
I am using .net core version 6. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can specify route as you want on method of the controller.

```
[Route("career/hiring-react")]
```

Use this Reference link to get it in details :

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection
2. https://stormpath.com/blog/routing-in-asp-net-core

Dynamically you can use like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{category}",
    defaults: new { category = "all" }
);
```

In the above code , controller & category both are dynamic.
So this is how you can configure dynamic routing.

Comment: You are taking it wrong. I want dynamic because URL changes on event. I have one method of the controller and if I would keep this route how can I change route everytime for that I need to amke different action merthods for that instead I want only one method

Comment: Yes. Go through these above links. That already have all the details for how you can define dynamic routing.

Comment: No its not there !